# URL link for amp-img

Tags: for-loop, url, hyperlink, amp-img

URL link for amp-img

How do I amp a image url instead of a regular image?

I have already tried to do a amp-html the regular way but it did not work.

Comment: Try to share what you've tried so far and didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add AMP Carousel like this :

```
<amp-carousel id="custom-button"  width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" type="slides" autoplay delay="2000">
<a href="https://www.example.com/amp/" target="_blank"> <amp-img src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/amp_img_1.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="AMP Carousel"></amp-img></a>
<a href="https://www.example2.com/amp/" target="_blank"> <amp-img src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/amp_img_2.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive" alt="AMP Carousel"></amp-img></a>
</amp-carousel>
```

And then You have to add CSS on anchor tag like this: `display:grid;`